# Enterprise Wiki Pages Suddenly Show Titles with %20, like the urls

Tags: sharepoint-online

This is happening in SharePoint Online.

I added a new page to my companies enterprise wiki site and now all pages in the wiki display the %20 in their titles in place of spaces.

[image: wiki title]

No settings on the site have been changes since this started happening. Is there a special character or something in this specific title causing this?

I have deleted the page and the error persists.